# Is there way of extracting the numerator of a Sympy rational expression?

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way of extracting the numerator of a Sympy rational expression?

This is what I have done thus far, with no success:

```
from fractions import Fraction
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol("x")

expn = sp.together(sp.expand(sp.together(x + 1/(x-2))))

expn.denominator
```

Ouput:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
      4 x = sp.Symbol("x")
      6 expn = sp.together(sp.expand(sp.together(x + 1/(x-2))))
----> 8 expn.denominator

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'denominator'
```

The expected result was:

*x - 2*

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fraction`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#fraction) or `expn.as_numer_denom()`

```
n, d = sp.fraction(expn)
print(f'Numerator:   {n}')
print(f'Denominator: {d}')
```

Output:

```
Numerator:   x**2 - 2*x + 1
Denominator: x - 2
```

Suggested by @OscarBenjamin, you can also use:

```
n = sp.numer(expn)
d = sp.denom(expn)
```

Comment: There is also `sp.numer(expn)` and `sp.denom(expn)`.

Comment: `fraction`, `numer` and `denom` are naive; `as_numer_denom` is not, e.g. for `1 + 1/x` the `denom` is ` while `as_numer_denom()` returns `(x + 1, x)`.